# jfrog started before the letsentrecryp certificate, now it doesn't work

Tags: jfrog-cli

After creating the certificate for the jfrog url, it stopped having access via the url. How can I know the reasons for the errors, possible errors, what log do I have to look at to locate the error? Is Java the cause?

JAVA VERSION > openjdk 11.0.22 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.22.0.7-1) (build 11.0.22+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.22.0.7-1) (build 11.0.22+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

> JFROG Version:
> jfrog-artifactory-oss.x86_64 7.27.10-72710900 @Artifactory
> Server: Rocky Linux 9

I didn't do anything to try to resolve it